# customer reg form magento

Tags: php, magento, magento2

[error in magento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH47p.png)
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Webkul\Otp\Helper\Data::getCountries() must be of the type array, null returned in /var/www/html/enirmaan/app/code/Webkul/Otp/Helper/Data.php:272 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/enirmaan/app/code/Webkul/Otp/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml(21): Webkul\Otp\Helper\Data->getCountries() #1 /var/www/html/enirmaan/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/html/e...') #2 /var/www/html/enirmaan/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register), '/var/www/html/e...', Array) #3 /var/www/html/enirmaan/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', Array) #4 /var/www/html/enirmaan/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Cu in /var/www/html/enirmaan/app/code/Webkul/Otp/Helper/Data.php on line 272

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can we have a copy of your code in class method Webkul\Otp\Helper\Data::getCountries() ? And details about your environment ?